# Neutralising a photos lighting by using a rebuilt scene to imitate the original light and using that as a counterbalance

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have this picture and I've recreated the scene (in its entirety, including off screen objects) in a bid to remove the lighting (sunlight coming through windows). So i created a sun lamp and tried to mimic the sun in the picture, rendered the image and took the diffuse direct because i assumed that would be the light, i inverted it so it would be the shadow instead of the light and tried to introduce it to the picture but it just looks terrible. My idea has failed miserably, i wonder if anyone else has an idea for how i could approach this.

Thanks for your time, it means a lot.
[image: Original picture with sunlight coming through the window]

[The rebuilt scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mYci.jpg)

[image: diffuse indirect]

Comment: What is the end result you're trying to achieve? It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to get a scene that is shaded flat without lighting?

Comment: Please use a title that makes sense. Questions are not answered based on their dramatic performance but on their clarity.

Comment: @stphnl329 Hi. The result im trying to achieve is neutralising the light on the the original photo by using a render of similar lighting to counterbalance and neutralise the photo, leaving it open for me to pick the lighting. I just want to make the original photo neutral so i can control the lighting without having the original lighting impact.

Comment: Block out your windows and use your own lighting. You don't need CGI here.

Comment: @Nick I find your answer obtuse, I do need CGI here, if you don't know the answer to the problem its ok not to answer.

Comment: You would need indirect pass, reflection of table ... as well, but you will never get satisfied result. Any pixel inaccuracy of rebuild scene will produce ugly artefacts. Try to run your image through some app for PBR material, there is action to eliminate lightning in image. After that use this image as projection texture, adjust details and relight.

Comment: Light is an even distribution, so shouldn't any weird artefacts be able to be blurred out or something, as the effect is meant to be quite subtle anyway. Hypothetically, were artefacts not a debilitating problem what would the setup for the compositing nodes look like to bring the indirect and reflection together? roughly. Please and Thanks @vklidu

Comment: @stphnl329 Yes, im trying to get it shaded flat without lighting so i can then light myself with the recreated scene. Its all photoscanned so it should be pretty accurate

Comment: @Sahns fair enough, wasn't a super helpful comment from me so sorry for that. It is a cool idea, I am just doubtful that it's possible to model a scene accurately enough to get a good result like this. If you look up _Technical Papers Preview: SIGGRAPH 2019_ on YouTube, one of the things there (at 1:40) shows dynamic relighting of a scene, so it's quite cutting edge stuff.